# Polynomial Linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I'm having difficulties with the green underline. I understand that basis here is $\{1,.....,x^r\}$ and $[T]_B $ is defined as being $A$, but I don't see why you can use prop 11.1. Is $q$ a linear transformation?

Comment: _As in 11.1, let $V$ be $n$-dimensional over..._ you are confusing that $V$ with the vector space of polynomials. That $V$ is any space, not necessarily that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding linear transformations corresponds to adding their matrices, multiplying the transformation by a scalar corresponds to multiplying the matrix by a scalar, and composing transformations corresponds to multiplying their matrices - this is where 11.1 comes into it.  So if $T$ has matrix $A$, then $T^2$ has matrix $A^2$, and for example $2T^2+3T$ has matrix $2A^2+3A$.  In general, for any polynomial $q$, the transformation $q(T)$ has matrix $q(A)$.

Other points: $q$ itself is not a linear transformation, it's a polynomial - but $q(T)$ is different, that **is** a linear transformation.  Also, the basis $B$ does not have to be $\{1,\ldots,x^r\}$, it could be any basis, just so long as it is consistent throughout the whole calculation.

Answer (score 1):

It could possibly be that they use it when deconstructing $[T^i]_B$ into $A^i$.

i.e. 
$[T^2]_B = [TT]_B$ (where $[TT]_B$ is the composition of $T$ with itself)

and

$[T^3]_B = [TT^2]_B = [T]_B [TT]_B = [T]_B [T]_B [T]_B = A.A.A = A^3$